# How can I use the PHP radius function with multiple variables?

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude

I have been reading up on radius and mysql and I am very confused on how to exactly implement the code with multiple search variables, so could someone break it down for me.

My database has the following tables:

> **idx** | **type** | **price** | **item_desc** | **s_lat** | **s_long** | **created date**

Here is my current code.

```
$search_origin_radius = "200";
$search_dest_radius = "100";
$search_origin_lat = "37.2629742";
$search_origin_long = "-98.286158";
$search_dest_lat = "37.2629742";
$search_dest_long = "-98.286158";
$type = "consumers";
$price = "100";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE `price` = '$price'";

if($type && !empty($type))
{
    $sql .= " AND `type` = '$type'";    
}
```

Everything I have found so far says to use :

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
    * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM myTable
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance
```

But I am super confused on how I implement it for `$search_origin_radius` and `$search_dest_radius`. Basically what I am trying to do is find everything that is for sale within the price range and radius around the two cities.

Example I want to find everything priced for $100 around Oklahoma City, OK within 200 miles and Kansas City, MO within 100 miles.

EDIT** As suggested added this as a stored function.

```
function Calc_Distance($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo,         $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 3959)
{
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```

Using new query but still nothing shows up:

```
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE Calc_Distance(s_lat, s_long, $search_origin_lat, $search_origin_long) < 200
  AND Calc_Distance(s_lat, s_long, $search_dest_lat,   $search_dest_long)   < 100
  AND price = $price
";
```

Comment: so your cos/sin function work but you want use `$search_origin_radius` ? Maybe a picture or some sample data could help to understand what you want.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. I do not know how to implement the cos/sin function into my current sql query.

Comment: can you show me a picture of what area between both cites are you interested?

Comment: There is no picture. I am not trying to find anything between the cities. I am trying to find everything for sell within a radius of both cities.

Comment: Yes but I dont understand what that mean. If you arent able to draw two circles meaybe you dont understand it neither. I dont know where are Oklahoma and Kansas

Comment: Think of any two cities you know, I want to find everything for sell (that is in my database) from those two cities but within a certain radius around them. I know what I mean, and I think I posted it pretty well on what I wanted, I think the language barrier might be causing your confusion.

Comment: I solve spatial problem every day, but if you dont put the extra effort to show the problem I wouldnt waste my time trying to understand it. Good luck

Comment: But who would want to know what's available around two cities? You can only be in one city at time!

Comment: It is for my company drivers. They are basically wanting a way to search for "Where they are AND where they are going" at the same time, without having to do two searches. Which I have that down, I can search two cities with the "AND" function. I just don't know how to bring up everything in the radius of those two cities.

Comment: ihave you tried mySQL `ST_Distance` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance

Answer (score 5):

Oklahoma City and Kansas City are pretty much 300 miles away from each other.

There is very little land that could be considered both under 200 miles from Oklahoma City `AND` under 100 miles from Kansas City, so I am not surprised your query returns no results.

Perhaps you wanted `OR` logic here..

```
SELECT id
  FROM products
 WHERE (*Oklahoma City distance calc miles* < 200
    OR *Kansas City distance calc miles* < 100)
   AND price = 100;
```

..or you could `UNION ALL` a `SELECT` for each city:

```
SELECT id, 'Oklahoma City' as city  
  FROM products
 WHERE *Oklahoma City distance calc miles* < 200
   AND price = 100

 UNION ALL

SELECT id, 'Kansas City'
  FROM products
 WHERE *Kansas City distance calc miles* < 100
   AND price = 100;
```

Personally I'd lean towards the second as it is easy to build in code and gives you which city the product is found for neatly.

Although as pointed out by @PaulSpiegel this (unmodified) could return some products more than once if the search areas intersect.

Comment: Well what I am going for is anything for sell within a 200 miles radius of Oklahoma City AND anything for sell within a 100 mile radius of Kansas City. So basically if there is anything around Oklahoma City, show it and if there is anything around Kansas City show it. So one could have zero results while the other does. Like right now in my DB, I put 3 things for sell in Kansas City and 2 in Oklahoma City. So I know there is stuff within the range, and if I do a single query for each city it shows results, but not both combined. If that makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, I get it, but if you `AND` together the two distance conditions you are saying they both have to be true! So either `OR` the two distance conditions together or use a `UNION ALL` to combine the results.

Comment: This is the right answer.  OP shouldn't be using AND.  What they are describing will only return something that is essentially halfway through the route from KC to OKC, which could have a use case BUT the distance would need to be variable rather than fixed at 200mi because the problem you addressed.

Comment: Note that the circles might intersect, so you can get a product twice (once per city) when using UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Stored Function that takes two pairs of lat and lng, and returns a distance.

```
$sql = "
SELECT ...
    FROM MyTbl
    WHERE Distance(s_lat, s_long, $search_origin_lat, $search_origin_long) < 200
      AND Distance(s_lat, s_long, $search_dest_lat,   $search_dest_long)   < 100
      AND price = $price
";
```

Or spell out the expression twice.

Comment: So Distance would be my stored function correct? Please see updated code, as it comes back with nothing in radius.

Comment: Don't use $variables in the function.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? Example?

Comment: Never mind..  I was reading your PHP function, thinking it was sql.  Doh!

Comment: No need to write this function, mysql already has it built-in for years...

Comment: @Shadow -- where is the Distance function?  Not until 5.7 with InnoDB is there a spherical distance.  (IIRC)

Comment: ST_Distance was added in v5.6.1

Comment: 5.7.6 SPATIAL: ST_Distance_Sphere() and ST_MakeEnvelope()

Answer (score 0):

> If you use MySQL version 5.7 you can use it's **Spatial Convenience
>   Functions** and more specifically [`ST_Distance_Sphere`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere). This way
>   you will have a result in meters and from there you could easily
>   calculate it in miles.
>
> If your MySQL version is 5.6.1 then you can use [`ST_Distance`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance)
>   function like in this MySQL-Fiddle [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fe81a)

```
SELECT *,ST_Distance(POINT(`s_lat`,`s_long`), POINT(35.5857,-97.4885))*68.925*1.60934 AS `exact_distance`
FROM `entries` WHERE `price`=100 
HAVING `exact_distance`<=200;
```

You will notice 2 constants (`68.925` and `1.60934`). 
The 1st one will convert the result of ST_Distance to miles
The second one (when added) will convert it to kilometers
In the above example `ST_Distance` is used to get the distance of a geography point from Oklahoma City. If you want to add another city in your `SELECT` query then something like this would be what you could use.

```
SELECT *,ST_Distance(POINT(`s_lat`,`s_long`), POINT(35.5857,-97.4885))*68.925 AS `exact_distance_from_Oklahoma_City`,
ST_Distance(POINT(`s_lat`,`s_long`), POINT(39.127562,-94.598810))*68.925 AS `exact_distance_from_Kansas_City`
FROM `entries` WHERE `price`=100 
HAVING `exact_distance_from_Oklahoma_City`<=200
AND `exact_distance_from_Kansas_City`<=100;
```